# gulp-run-sequence does not finish task

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have the following gulp-tasks defined.
They should revision static files and replace links to them.

```
var config                  = require('./config');

var gulp                    = require('gulp');
var rev                     = require('gulp-rev');
var revNapkin               = require('gulp-rev-napkin');
var revReplace              = require('gulp-rev-replace');
var runSequence             = require('run-sequence');

var manifest_src            = gulp.src('./' + config.base.dest + '/manifest.json');

var revStatic = function() {
  return gulp.src([config.base.dest + '/**/*', '!' + config.base.dest + '/**/*+(css|js|json|html)'])
    .pipe(rev())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.base.dest))
    .pipe(revNapkin({verbose: false}))
    .pipe(rev.manifest(config.base.dest + '/manifest.json', {merge: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(''));
}

var revUpdateRef = function() {
    return gulp.src(config.base.dest + '/**/**.{css,js}')
    .pipe(revReplace({manifest: manifest_src}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.base.dest));
}

var revCSSJS = function() {
    return gulp.src(config.base.dest + '/**/*.{css,js}')
    .pipe(rev())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.base.dest))
    .pipe(revNapkin({verbose: false}))
    .pipe(rev.manifest(config.base.dest + '/manifest.json', {merge: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(''));
}

var revUpdateHTML = function() {
    return gulp.src(config.base.dest + '/**/*.html')
    .pipe(revReplace({manifest: manifest_src}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.base.dest));
}

var revTask = function(cb) {
    runSequence('rev:static', 'rev:updateRef', 'rev:cssjs',  'rev:updateHTML', cb)
}

gulp.task('rev:static', revStatic);
module.exports = revStatic;

gulp.task('rev:updateRef', revUpdateRef);
module.exports = revUpdateRef;

gulp.task('rev:cssjs', revCSSJS);
module.exports = revCSSJS;

gulp.task('rev:updateHTML', revUpdateHTML);
module.exports = revUpdateHTML;

gulp.task('rev', revTask);
module.exports = revTask;
```

If I run the tasks each other by hand everything is fine. However if I ran the task 'rev' that consist of all the rev tasks run by run-sequence the last task 'rev:updateHTML' is not finished.

My console output looks like this

```
 ~/working/gulp-workflow/$gulp rev
[14:33:41] Using gulpfile ~/working/gulp-workflow/gulpfile.js
[14:33:41] Starting 'rev'...
[14:33:41] Starting 'rev:static'...
[14:33:41] Finished 'rev:static' after 204 ms
[14:33:41] Starting 'rev:updateRef'...
[14:33:41] Finished 'rev:updateRef' after 38 ms
[14:33:41] Starting 'rev:cssjs'...
[14:33:41] Finished 'rev:cssjs' after 26 ms
[14:33:41] Starting 'rev:updateHTML'...
 ~/working/gulp-workflow/$
```

I can´t find any error in my tasks, but I guess there is an error with the stream running async.
I hope you can help me and point out my error.

Comment: Can you remove `rev:updateHTML` and see if `rev:cssjs` will hang as well?

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of having `.pipe(gulp.dest(''))` ? That's the only weird statement I see in this code...

Comment: If I remove rev:updateHTML, the task finishes and rev:cssjs is executed.

Comment: The 
    `.pipe(gulp.dest(''));`
is there to write the manifest file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not totally wrong, gulp does not recognize, if the task has been finished or not. Therefore you can use `done` as a parameter and execute it whenever pipe has been finished. So actually something like this:

```
var revUpdateHTML = function(done) {
  return gulp.src(config.base.dest + '/**/*.html')
  .pipe(revReplace({manifest: manifest_src}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.base.dest))
  .on('end', function() {
    done();
  });
}
```